# How to undo an added element to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am making an application where now I need to ask the user for a few names (the players), I am storing these values in an `ArrayList`.

It all works perfectly but what I'd like to know is:

**How do I let the user undo his choice if he wants to change a name he's already submitted?**

Consider I'm asking to type the names into an `EditText` which then, thanks to a `button`, gets its value stored in that `ArrayList` and then cleared (the `EditText`).

So another question would be, **how do I keep the keyboard displayed? AS it's really annoying to close and open it back again everytime you need to add a name** (24 is the limit so it may be very annoying!)**.**

This is the logic part:

```
public void getName(View view){
    if(playersAmount > 0) {
        names.add(name.getText().toString());
        name.setText("");
        playersAmount--;
    }else{
        name.setEnabled(false);
        if(playersAmount == -1){
            //Intent
            Toast.makeText(getNames.this, "Nice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        playersAmount--;
    }
}
```

`playersAmount` is an `int` I retrieved from the previous `activity` via the `intent`.

Comment: Does the user type all the names into one `EditText`, which is then later parsed on a button press? If not, it sounds as thought that might be a good approach (split the names by `','` or `\\s+`, for instance) as then the user could just enter everything at once. Or, are all the names entered individually?

Comment: All the names are entered individually, after submitted each via a button the EditText gets cleared so you can add a new name, by the way if you've a better way to achieve this, feel free to share that! @PPartisan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a temp variable that stores the previous name. And once the undo button is clicked, you can reassign the name as the temp variable.

You can do it like the following:

```
temp = "SomeName";
names.set(names.size()-1, temp);
```

The reason for `names.size()-1` is because I'm assuming each time you add a name, it'll get stored at the end of `names`.

More information on ArrayList's set(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)

---

If that's not what you're looking for, you can simply remove the last element of `names` and continue with adding new names.

For example, if you had a button called "Undo", each time you press it, it will trigger the following:

```
if(/*Undo is clicked*/) {
    names.remove(names.size()-1);
}
...
// Continue with your code of adding names
...
```

More information on ArrayList's remove(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)

Comment: Oh, right, how did I check if the user hit the undo button?

Comment: Well for that you'd need to create a separate button and have it invoke the new `set()` method. There should be a lot of example online on how to create a button and have it invoke a method through onClickListener.

Comment: You gave me a nice idea, I think I'll create that undo button and have a TextView saying how many players are left to name that in the undo case will increase, thank you!

Comment: If it works (sure it will) I'll mark this as the answer, have a nice day

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To remove something from an ArrayList, you have to have an instance of it.  Here, in your code you are using `name.getText().toString()` and then setting `name.setText("")`.

A better strategy is to use just `name` and rework `getNames` to return an array of the `name.getText()` themselves or to (better) use just `name`.

If you want to remove based on index, you can do that too with an ArrayList by accessing it via:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Index Zero");
list.add("Index One");
...
System.out.println(list[0]);
```

Comment: May I ask for an example as I'm new to this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method I suggested in my comments would involve the user entering all the names they like in an `EditText`, with each name separated by a comma. The following method would extract all the names:

```
public static String[] getNamesFromEditText(EditText editText) {

    String editTextContent = editText.getText().toString();
    String[] allNames = editTextContent.split(",");

    //Remove any leading and trailing blank spaces from each name
    for (String name : allNames) {
        name = name.trim();
    }

    return allNames;

}
```

The advantage to doing it this way would be that the user could add or delete as much as they like before they confirm their choices. The disadvantage is that this method wouldn't work if they didn't use the correct syntax and separate each name by a comma.

Comment: True, not sure everybody will be so smart :P